# To pass the values on another page in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm working on to pass the values from one page to another. I'm passing the values with navigation.

I tried this code

```
     this.props.navigation.navigate('welcome', 
      {JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item:this.state.email,}))
in parent class from which i'm sending.
     const { navigation } = this.props;
     const JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item = 
     navigation.getParam('JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item', 'NO-ID');
     <Text>JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item: 
    {JSON.stringify(JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item)}</Text>
```

this is the second class where i want data.

This is my code

```
this.state = { email: '', password: '', error: ''};
   firebase.auth()
   .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
   password).then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
   .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('welcome', 
   {JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item:this.state.emai

l,}))
```

set the text input

```
<TextInput
      style={{height: 40,width:250,  borderRadius: 5  
     ,multiline:"true",borderColor: 'purple', 
      borderWidth: 2,
    }}
    value={this.state.email}
    secureTextEntry={false}
    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
    placeholder="email"
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
    this.focusNextField('Password');
    }}
    returnKeyType={ "next" }
    ref={ input => {
    this.inputs['email'] = input;
    }} 
    />
```

set the text input on the second class to get data

```
renderComponent() {
   const { navigation } = this.props;
   const JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item = 
   navigation.getParam('JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item', 'NO-ID');

   if (this.state.loggedIn) {
   return (
    <View>

      <Text>JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item: 
   {JSON.stringify(JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item)}</Text>
   <Button
    title="Sign out"
    onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()} 

    />

    </View>
  );
```

I'm getting the blank data on the second page. I just want that when I fill the email and click the button I get the email on next page

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {



render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              itemId: 86,
              otherParam: 'anything you want here',
            });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    /* 2. Get the param, provide a fallback value if not available */
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
    const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
    <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

here is a sample that you can pass data to another page but first do these steps

1. yarn add react-navigation
2. yarn add react-native-gesture-handler
3. react-native link react-native-gesture-handler

you can also visit following 2 pages

1. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html --> FOR INSTALLING NAVIGATION
2. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html --> FOR PASSING DATA

Comment: ausgezeichnete Antwort

Answer (score 0):

sender

```
       `this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
          itemId: 86,
          otherParam: 'anything you want here',
        });`
```

receiver

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');
```

check documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)

Comment: i'm also doing the same but i'm enable to find the error between the two

Comment: check by console this.props.navigation.state.params on receiver side

Comment: I even set the alert to see the result and alert is also prinitng blank

Comment: the problem is i'm putting `this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
          itemId: 86,

Comment: this like this  this.props.navigation.navigate('welcome',{JSON_ListView_Clicked_Item:this.state.email,}))

Comment: i want that whenever i filled the email input and press the submit button it will display on second page

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/navigate-with-params-v3  run this example first and then compare with your code .

Comment: create a repo and give link

Comment: it's a very large project i done with firebase but only in which i'm stuck is this.

Comment: i have created snack which is related to these classes only hope it'll help you

Comment: place this.props.navigation.navigate('welcome',{hello:this.state.email,}) in  onLoginSuccess function and put consoles in function